# Passport.js failing to serialize user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js for Google, Facebook and Twitter logins only.

Node.js v0.8.19 with express.js 3.1.0, and passportjs version 0.1.16.
(passport-facebook - 0.1.5, twitter - 0.1.4 passport-goolge-oauth - 0.1.5 )

Everything works fine for a while, after an hour or so of the app running passport.js stops serializing the user into the req.user session.

Facebook and google are receiving meaning full data from their respective api's

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      var temp = {} 
      temp.name = profile.displayName
      temp.id = profile.id
      console.log(temp)
      return done(null, temp);
}));
```

The console.log here will successfully print user id and name, however after calling

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});
```

Serialize and deserialize are taken from the passport-facebook [example.](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/examples/login/app.js)

The user will not be attached to req.user.

Twitter never gets that far, after returning to the callback url, twitter gives the error:

```
Error: failed to find request token in session
[03/11 23:28:24 GMT]     at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate
```

**Note:** these failures only happen after a period of time, the work properly for a while. Thats why I think it may be a memory issue, like Im saving the session in memory instead of a cooke.

This is my express app configuration

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'tobo!', cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() +     3600000), }}));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

I have looked at the mailing list etc, but I could not find something matching this problem.
I have checked on my localhost and on a nodejitsu server. Everything works for a while then fails.

Comment: Neither passport.serializeUser() or deserializeUser() look like they could ever work. serializeUser() is supposed to take an object and serialize it into a string that can be used in a cookie to uniquely identify a user. That is usually done by calling `done(null, user.id)`. deserializeUser is supposed to take the same id (from a cookie) and find the correct set of data in a database. With mongodb you could do `User.findById(id, function(err, user) { done(err, user); });`

Comment: So they must be strings?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/examples/login/app.js) in the passport-facebook example they have the same serialize and deserialize as I do.

Comment: Hm... now I'm not sure. I haven't used the facebook strategy in particular, but i assume it should always work the same. [In passport's own docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) serializeUser returns a string (which is what the name implies), so iäd place my bet on that it's the docs for passport-facebook that is wrong. If you don't return something else than what was sent to serializeUser, those methods doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: My understanding was that you use serialize to pick what you want saved to the session, and that deserialize is when you get find your user based on an identifier, in my case I only want an id and name in the cookie and not saved to a db. So I return the object I want in the session and deserialize does not need to do anything, thus it returns what it gets. I feel like this is okay, because my code above works for a time period before breaking.

Comment: @JohnEcho you're using `maxAge` as if it was `expires`, which might be the problem. `maxAge` should be passed the number of milliseconds after which the session expires (whereas `expires` takes a timestamp, as in your code)

Comment: you are correct, will check that out.

Comment: (hmm did some more thinking and that shouldn't be the problem, it will just set a really long expiry time)

Comment: Check this out instead: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/issues/12#issuecomment-10210714

Comment: Seems to be the same error, however there is no solution there for me, as my issue is not attached to localhost.

Answer (score 26):

First you must understand what serialize and deserialize are meant for.

1) `serializeUser` take a user object and store any information you want in the session, when you return `done(null, user)`, as per your first question.

2) `deserializeUser` take the information stored in the session (sent by cookieSession in every request) and checks if the session is still valid for a user, and `if(!err) done(null,user)` is true, keeps the user in the session, where `else done(err,null)` removes it from the session, redirecting you to whatever your `app.get('/auth/:provider/callback')` sends the user to after checking if the session is timed out or not. This should clarify things for your second question.

Answer (score 6):

I still do not understand why the problem came about but I have solved it by doing the following.

Changing

```
  app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'tobo!', cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() +     3600000), }}));
```

to

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'tobo!', maxAge: 360*5 }));
```

I think that serializing the entire user object should work since deserializeUser will just pass back the passed cookie. But by not serializing the entire user object it is working.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser: ' + user._id)
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.users.findById(id, function(err, user){
        console.log(user)
        if(!err) done(null, user);
        else done(err, null)  
    })
});
```

I have had **zero** issues since I did this.

Comment: Not sure if this is actually the issue, but I think `maxAge` on the cookie is supposed to be the number of seconds the cookie is supposed to last, not the actual time that it should expire (which is what you put there).

Answer (score 0):

```js
//app.use(session(...)) must comes before app.user(passport.session())
//other wise items will not be save or serialize to session


app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);


app.use(passport.session());
```